# ATX - replace passive PFC to active

Tags: atx, power-factor-correction

I have some ATX PSU with passive PFC (huge coil with capacitor).
I also have some active PFC from other ATX that based on L6561 IC.

This psu will handle odroid xu4 board and few led strips based on ws2812b chip.

I have limited space in this box and probably will need remove this passive coil or use this active board...

Can I replace it, or is there something that block this idea?

P.S.

Picture of boards:
[image]

Best Regards.

Comment: Do you have extensive knowledge about the dangers involved like death by electrocution and fire?

Comment: Yes, thats not the issue in my case.

Comment: Please, add some detailed photos about your targets (inside of them). We are not at all sure if we talk the same language. Edit your question, do not add comments.

Comment: Can your existing PSU handle 400 V DC on the input?

Comment: There are two capacitor rated at 200v each in series. The same was used in board where I found active PFC.

Comment: Sure, but do you have margins left on voltage on the transistor, voltage-time area on the transformer during startup without saturating and so on?

Comment: What winny is hinting at: These active PFC circuits tend to be step-up converters of some sort... Oh BTW, do not attempt to put a fuse or power switch between PFC and board - if these parts  can switch 230VAC (which is ~400V peak) that does NOT mean they can switch 400V DC!

Answer (score 2):

Do a test run. The active PFC board, the big capacitors and a passive load. If your board is self-contained (=needs nothing from the PSU) you can easily find how high voltage you get into your capacitors with different loads. The highest value must not exceed the peak mains voltage. You need a meter that can show peak voltages. An oscilloscope is a kind of russian roulette due the signal ground connection. You should have isolation transformers and be agilently conscious on what you do to keep the mains voltage out of your fingers and the oscilloscope input.